# Thingpark Enterprise question on Applications

Tags: aws-iot, thingpark

We've been  using Thingpark Enterprise cloud for a while now and we 're facing a difficulty in adding new Application outputs to our existing devices.

We 're using MQTT as an output on an existing project (about 2k devices) and we need to extend our infrastructure with AWS cloud using AWS IoT.

It seems to be no way to group-add the devices into new Applications outputs (from existing / already imported devices), not even an API endpoint to call (let's say using devEUI as a parameter to add to a new Application).

With a larger number of devices, it becomes really time-consuming to manually add each device using the dashboard one-by-one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We do have a set of REST APIs (named Dx-API) that will help you automate this type of mass-update tasks.
From the ThingPark Enterprise UI, you can get access to the APIs from  the "Help" menu.
For your specific issue, these are the steps you need to follow:

1. Obtain an authentication token (POST /oauth/token) using Dx-Admin API => https://thingparkenterprise.eu.actility.com/thingpark/dx/admin/latest/swagger-ui/index.html?shortUrl=tpdx-admin-tpe-api-contract.json#!/Token/post_oauth_token
2. List your set of applications using Dx-Core API and collect the routeRef (ID of application) for the new desired target => https://thingparkenterprise.eu.actility.com/thingpark/dx/core/latest/swagger-ui/index.html?shortUrl=tpdx-core-tpe-api-contract.json#/Device/get_routes
3. Update your set of devices with the expected routeRef target => https://thingparkenterprise.eu.actility.com/thingpark/dx/core/latest/swagger-ui/index.html?shortUrl=tpdx-core-tpe-api-contract.json#/Device/put_devices__deviceRef_

**Warning** : The domain name needs to be edited depending on the regional SaaS platform which you are using (European, Australian or USA platform):

- thingparkenterprise.eu.actility.com
- thingparkenterprise.au.actility.com
- thingparkenterprise.us.actility.com

Let me know if you need more information.